# Composer classmap and loading files with non-standard extensions

Tags: php, file, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

When loading files through the composer **classmap** functionality is it possible to load PHP files that have non-standard extensions such as `myFileName.stub` or `myFileName.foo` ?

At present it seems not to be loading them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer will currently include files with the following extensions:

.php
.inc
.hh

The last one is for HHVM stuff.

Relevant lines from the class map generator here:

https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php#L62
https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php#L76

So, looks like you'll need a custom map generator...

Comment: Where can i find more information/docs about custom map generators?

Comment: It's not a a current feature of Composer.

Comment: Here is a sample code change to add the feature though (fork)  https://github.com/tomwalder/composer/commit/023c2f00088472d4d513f2599ce4cc52e9d4b93d

Comment: This answer saved me a day.

Comment: Is there maybe a chance to create a composer plugin to add support for custom extensions ?
I have a similar problem when i try to load files with names like `customclass.class.php` or `custuminterface.interface.php`